# Iterate through tail output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am tailing lines from a file. And I need to iterate through the output to do some processing.

File Content:

```
abcd abcd abcd
abcd abcd
abcd abcd
xyz xyz
lmno xvz
pqrs uvw xyz
```

Below is my snippet that I use.

```
file=extract.txt
for line in $(tail -n 2 ${file})
do
  echo $line
done
```

The output that i am expecting is this

```
lmno xvz
pqrs uvw xyz
```

The out that I am seeing is this, somehow the white spaces are treated as newline printing each words in single line. Appreciate any help on this. I need to iterate through the actual lines to do some processing.

```
lmno
xvz
pqrs
uvw
xyz
```

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/questions/363559/why-you-dont-read-lines-with-for-in-bash

Comment: Please read the descriptions of tags before applying them. You can [edit] your Q to fix them.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common problems in your shell code.  The [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports include links to additional information, including fixes.

Comment: There are a few problems with `echo $line`.  `printf '%s\n' "$line"` is good.  See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/4154375) and the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).

Answer (score 2):

Use a pipe, not `for`.

```
tail -n 2 "$file" | while read -r line
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```

Don't forget to quote your variables so you don't get unexpected word splitting and wildcard expansion.